# “Once” or “When” question

Tags: word-usage

> My financial guarantee has been submitted **once** I applied for AU.

Is “once” used correctly in this sentence? Or should I say “when I applied” instead?

Comment: The tenses are inconsistent. It might be easier to rearrange it. Assuming *you* submitted it, you could say, "Once I had applied for AU I submitted my f.g." or "Having applied for AU I submitted my f.g." or "After applying for AU I submitted my f.g."

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: A simple up-vote is thanks enough :-)